# microsoft access link to backend database

Tags: hyperlink

I have a front end Microsoft access database with forms, reports etc. and a backend access database.

I wish to run the front end on various machines, and place the backend (the data) on either a server or network attached storage.

Would I need a copy of Microsoft Access for the backend server? Or can I just connect to it using the front end and simply store it there?